# Is it possible to customize Recaptcha image language?

Tags: zend-framework, recaptcha

Is it possible to customize Recaptcha to display text in English only words?
As recently, I found that text could be displayed in other language like Hebrew.

Here is example:

[image]

To be honest it is not possible to type such words for ordinary users having keyboard with Roman alphabet and not many know that image can be redrawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, via the API you may only customize the interface, not the images.

[reCAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReCAPTCHA) uses scans from the real books, so sometimes, even in latin books there are some non latin characters too.

But there should be no problem here. reCAPTCHA displays always two words: one unknown even for the reCAPTCHA (probably the Hebrew in this case), and the other one, which is really checked.

So the user may misspell the Hebrew, but it's OK when he types the other one (latin) word as expected.

(Only guesses, but I think that's how this thing works).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at: http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/customization.html#i18n?

That's the API. It talks about setting the translation, but I've never used it, so I'm not 100% sure whether it can do what you want.

Due to where Recaptcha gets its captcha string from (text scanned from books), it could very well be limited to languages that use the Latin alphabet.

I bet that *Reviled* is the challenge word (the one scanned from the book) and the other is the test word (the one it uses to verify whether or not the person who typed the challenge word is actually typing something legitimate or not).

Comment: Yes I went through documentation the only customization you can make is to change interface language not actual text. The funny part about it that 90% of visitors would not be able to type in Hebrew or any other non Roman language.

Comment: Pretty much what I suspected. Recaptcha is Latin script only. Or, mostly Latin script. There have been times I've seen a math symbol or Greek letter, but those are rare. Recaptha uses scanned books. There are PHP math based captcha libraries. These display captchas that are simple math problems (like 21 - 3). All the user has to do is provide an answer. At least the numbers are more or less the same on almost all keyboards. Have you looked into that? Sorry I can't give you more help.